# Weather Indicator not showing icons?

Tags: 11.04, weather

I searched here and didn't see this question already posted, but my apologies if I already missed it.

I've noticed lately that my Weather Indicator applet is no longer showing weather icons. If I select it to pull information from Google, I get this:

[image]

However, if I select it to pull from Yahoo, the weather icon displays in the notification area, but will not show icons in the forecast menu, like this:

[image]

I've tried completely removing and re-installing Weather Indicator without any success. Any ideas?

EDIT: Changing the icon theme does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: fixed now from proposed updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having switched icon themes, I too noticed that I would not get the icons to display for the forecast.  Without experimentation, (I am guessing somewhat here) I suspect it is my choice of icon theme that is preventing the icon display.  Let me take a look and determine if this is the case.

Alright, I took a look and it would appear that my initial inclination was incorrect.  That is, I tried changing the icon theme, refreshed the weather indicator and came up with the same results.  I know that it was working at some point.  Perhaps something has gone awry on Yahoo's end.

Comment: It could very well be that, although I just tried changing my icon theme several times and it didn't seem to help. 

Edit: I find it intriguing that it's happening with Google, too.

Comment: Did we recently have a weather-indicator update?

Comment: I don't remember seeing an update in the repository's/update manager, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Update came through this morning for me.  Everything appears to be functioning properly.

Answer (score 5):

Google changed the icons without advertisement. New version of My-Weather-Indicator was released to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer for indicator-weather, which is what it looks like you're using.  As @atareao mentioned, Google changed its icons. Yahoo should still work for current weather, but all forecasts are from Google and so will also be broken.

If you want to keep using indicator-weather, I recommend installing our [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team/+archive/ppa): ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa .  The version in the ubuntu repositories does not get updated frequently, and our PPA version has many new bug fixes.  There's more information on our [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WeatherIndicator/).

Once you've updated to the new version, don't forget to quit and reopen indicator-weather to get the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after switching from Google to Yahoo icons came back. But If I switch back to Google the problem appears again. With yahoo it already been working for  more than 10 minutes, hope it will stay the same way :-)

Comment: Switching to Google will display the forecast icons, but the indicator icon goes back to a "?". If I go back to Yahoo, the indicator icon shows but the forecast icons still don't. Weird.

Comment: I just tried switching from Yahoo to Google and found that my panel icon was similar to what @Chris posted.  Upon switching back to Yahoo, I gained the panel icon again.  In either case, the forecast shows no icons.

Comment: And now my Google forecast icons aren't showing either. HUH...

Comment: Yep, you are right about forecast icons. For me it even says "Unknown error occurred while picking up weather data" with no forecast at all.

Comment: i had it on google. with same problem, after switching to yahoo it's solved.