# Weather indicator doesn't launch after startup

Tags: 11.10, indicator

I've got 2 problems with weather indicator in Ubuntu 11.10 with unity.

1) The weather indicator doesn't launch after starting up the system.

2) The icon which is supposed to show clouds or a sun etc. shows a question mark insted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, just add it to your startup applications. Click the power icon (top right of your screen) and choose 'Startup applications'. Add one with the command `indicator-weather` like in the image below.

For the second problem, this is a known intermittent bug with Google. Switch to Yahoo! as the source in the preferences. You right-click on the indicator to access the preferences dialogue.

[image]

Comment: I suffer from the second issue, the question mark instead of the weather icon. Have tried switching to Yahoo and it works for a couple of seconds then reverts back to the question mark.

Comment: @Victor9098 Try Felix's answer in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45593/weather-indicator-not-showing-icons and see andrewsomething's reply here, too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55994/why-does-my-indicator-weather-sometimes-turn-gray There are many similar posts on this issue, no single solution yet.