# How to know the exact command to set as a startup program?

Tags: startup-applications

I was looking for a way to set my weather indicator to launch right after the system startup.

I've found a [nice and clear answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97053/weather-indicator-doesnt-launch-after-startup). The answer says that the command to add to the startup programs is **indicator-weather**.

My question is, how may I know in advance that the command is "indicator-weather"? Why not "weather-indicator"? **Where do I get that kind of information from?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways to know the exact command to start an application.

- Using the command-line and `dpkg`:

  ```
  $ dpkg -S indicator-weather | grep "/bin/"
  /usr/bin/indicator-weather
  ```
- Or by looking at the package file list on [package.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/):

  http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/indicator-weather/filelist

Both methods should help you to find the right command (e.g `indicator-weather`)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/usr/share/applications` directory location (or your respective application location) and right-click to see properties. you will get the command field. This is the required command for you to use it for start-up command.

If it is not in application search the location of the executable file from `whereis <nameofprogram>`. It will give you many places (you need to search among them, generally from `/usr/bin` location). Then after finding the exact location of executable file use that path as command in startup application.